# How can I detect each tr in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to change the colour of the button when I hover over the `tr` for example when hover over the first row, the button in it should have a different background colour than the other buttons.
this HTML code:

```
   <tr onmouseover="hoverMe()" onmouseout="outMe()">
    <input type="button" class="btn-table-book" value="book">
    </tr>
  <tr onmouseover="hoverMe()" onmouseout="outMe()">
    <input type="button" class="btn-table-book" value="book">
    </tr>
   <tr onmouseover="hoverMe()" onmouseout="outMe()">
    <input type="button" class="btn-table-book" value="book">
    </tr>
```

java script code

```
<script>
     function hoverMe(){
            $(".btn-table-book").css("background-color","#F0562B");
         $(".btn-table-book").css("color","#FFF");};
  function outMe(){

         $(".btn-table-book").css("background-color","#DDD");
         $(".btn-table-book").css("color","#222");
       };
```

after I run this code when I hover over any `tr` all button's colour change at the same time and I don't need this.

Comment: have you considered css `:hover` instead?

Comment: No I forget it and go to js direct ,thank's alot  sir . It work properly .

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not certain, there's a bit of a language barrier --  but I'm pretty sure he was saying your suggestion worked properly, and thanking you for it.  So maybe no need to tear into him for going down the wrong track at first.

Comment: oh, yeah, now that I read it again I can see your point @DanielBeck - comment removed :p though, I did like my analogy :p

Answer (score 3):

The `:hover` doesn't have to be on the last element of the selector.  Here's how to do that in plain CSS:

```
tr .btn-table-book {
    background-color: #DDD;
    color: #222;
}
tr:hover .btn-table-book {
    background-color: #F0562B;
    color: #FFF
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question what you need is this:

```
$('#tableId').find('tr').each(function(i){
     $(this).css("background-color","#DDD");
     $(this).css("color","#FFF");

     $(this).hover(function(){
          $(this).css("background-color","#F0562B");
          $(this).css("color","#222");
     });
  });
```

This will loop inside the first element and it will add the hover functionallity to each on of your tr elements.